# How do I loop a movie infinitely on another monitor?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, video-player

I want to loop a video infinitely in another monitor. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do such a thing, but here is one way you can do it.

First set up Dual Monitors for your Computer. Refer the following links:
[How to make the most of dual monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7454/how-to-make-the-most-of-dual-monitors)
[Multiple monitors, multiple workspaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces)

After you have set that up, you can just run VLC or any other media Player on one of the monitors, playing the desired movie, with `Loop One` enabled in the Media Player.