# Show docky on second monitor

Tags: docky

I installed a new monitor and I connected it to my laptop, but I can't reach to [DOCKY](http://wiki.go-docky.com/) on secondary monitor, while on my laptop it is available.

Can docky be shown on every monitor?

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can have docky on both monitors. However, you can move it to the monitor where you want it.
The site https://answers.launchpad.net/do/+question/60850 says:

1. Right click "Docky"
2. Click "Settings"
3. Notice "Drag to Reposition" help cue at the bottom?
4. Drag you dock while in "Settings" mode to whichever desktop you want.

Maybe you will find something useful here [How to make the most of dual monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7454/how-to-make-the-most-of-dual-monitors)